# Has to click button twice

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, button, focus

In my `MainActivity` I click a `Button` to open a `Fragment`, then from the `Fragment` I can click a `Button` to go to a second `Fragment`. But when the second `Fragment` opens, I have to click twice to make the buttons work. I think it has something to do with the `Fragment` not having focus, since I can click anywhere on the screen, which then enables the buttons so the second click will register button clicks normally. Both the `FAB` and normal button have the issue.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/capture_image"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGoBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/camera_error"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_back_arrow"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_send"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/iv"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my `Fragment` I initialize the `FAB` and `Button`, and assign click listeners:

```
mFab.setOnClickListener(this);
mExitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab:
                endFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.bGoBack:
                endFragment();
                break;
        }
    }
```

From my first `Fragment` i go to `Fragment` two like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Fragment2.newInstance())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

I have already tried to set the `focusable`, `focusable` in `touchmode` to true and set them to false. Also tried to request focus on the root view.

**EDIT**

Layout file of first Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.adrissa.localsnap.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/image_capture_top_bottom_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/capture_image"
        android:src="@drawable/button_capture_image"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

OnCreate method of second fragment:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate layout resource
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,
                container, false);

        // set status bar color to invisible to take and show image in full screen.
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        // initialize views
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mExitButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bGoBack);

        //set onClickListeners
        mFab.setOnClickListener(this);
        mExitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Get screen size as imageView will fill entire screen.
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int targetW = size.x;
        int targetH = size.y;

        // Get the path of the captured image
        String mCurrentPhotoPath = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getImagePath();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        Log.d("bitmap", "target w" + targetW + " target h" + targetH + " photo w" + photoW + " photo h" + photoH);

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return view;
    }
```

EDIT 2

MainActivity layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                                 tools:context="com.adrissa.image.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see any log from the `onClick()` method?

Comment: No the method is not called in my first click.

Comment: Do you already tried to use `SupportFragmentManager` insted of `FragmentManager`? I suggest you to post the code of the layout of first fragment and the onCreateView method of second fragment

Comment: Just added the code you wanted

Comment: Where is the `R.id.container` view?

Comment: In my MainActivity hosting the two Fragments. The cpntainer is also the one i use for the first fragment which works fine.

Comment: Can you post the code of your activity layout also?

Comment: just added the layout

Comment: Hm, did you try implement the click listener on Button (and FAB) instead of fragments? (also in your first fragment)

Comment: In my first fragment i use onClickListener, I have tried using the other method in the second fragment, but with the same result.

Comment: You could try to hide the first fragment when you are replacing it. Did you try this?

Comment: It is still the same result. Has to click twice.